# I installed kibana in linux but it's not working

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, kibana

I have used kibana and elasticsearch in windows my local pc.
but there is some error i'm facing when I working with kibana which is installed on linux server.
I installed elasticsearch and kibana version 7.9.2 on linux server.
I assign port 5601 as log.gurukul.ninja.
when I open log.gurukul.ninja in browser I can't see kibana there.
I'm new to linux server for elasticsearch and kibana .
I would like to know how to work with it.
for more details :

**kibana.yml**

```
server.port: 5601
server.host: "175.101.13.126"
server.name: "Ninja Logs"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://127.0.0.1:9200"]
elasticsearch.username: "something"
elasticsearch.password: "something"
```

**elasticsearch.tml**

```
xpack.security.enabled: true
```

**error**

```
log   [10:15:26.879] [warning][plugins-discovery] Expect plugin "id" in camelCase, but found: beats_management
  log   [10:15:26.890] [warning][plugins-discovery] Expect plugin "id" in camelCase, but found: triggers_actions_ui
  log   [10:15:36.150] [info][plugins-service] Plugin "visTypeXy" is disabled.
  log   [10:15:36.151] [info][plugins-service] Plugin "auditTrail" is disabled.
  log   [10:15:36.421] [warning][config][deprecation] Config key [monitoring.cluster_alerts.email_notifications.email_address] will be required for email notifications to work in 8.0."
  log   [10:15:36.443] [fatal][root] { Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 175.101.13.126:5601
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1263:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1328:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1461:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
  errno: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '175.101.13.126',
  port: 5601 }

 FATAL  Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 175.101.13.126:5601
```

Comment: Did u try installing elasticsearch with docker?

Comment: no i don't know how to install with docker. i'm windows guy.

Comment: You can install docker on windows.

Comment: yes, In my local pc (windows) i already installed. but for production i need to install on linux

Comment: what is result of "ip r" command? I think you dont have that IP on your interfaces

Answer (score 0):

you should define kibana `server.host` as external IP or hostname in kibana.yml.

```
server.host: "log.gurukul.ninja"
```

or something like this:

```
server.host: "192.168.1.10"
```

default configuration is localhost and you can see kibana dashboard via http://localhost:5601

Comment: you are doing somting wrong. share log. share kibana.yml and elasticsearch.yml